# regular expression for finding few strings in between one long string

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for regex pattern to extract the two words from a given text. I am looking for regex for applying in config file which would substitute in java code

For example - I have a long string - pabc_extracted_data_US_NETFLI_2020-11-26-17-02-03.csv.gz
I want to extract whatever string coming after **pabc_extracted_data_** (here US) and also looking for another regex for whatever string coming after **pabc_extracted_data_US_** (here NETFLI)..

so my expected output for two regex would be US & NETFLI. Please help me as I'm new to this regex world

Comment: You should try to format your message better. It could also help by telling in what language you are developing. Because the regex could differ.

Comment: A little extra detail would be useful.  Do you know that these "strings" will be only letters and not numbers?  Will they be all caps?

Answer (score -1):

edited:
first regex will be something like:

```
pabc_extracted_data_([^_]+)_
```

second will be something like:

```
pabc_extracted_data_[^_]+_([^_]+)
```

this seems to work:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am looking for two regex.. one for US other for NETFLI

Comment: @BigD, what language are you working in?  Regex may not be the easiest solution.  For example, if you're working in JavaScript, you could just split in the `'_'` character and take the elements of the array at certain positions.  Also, without specifying the language, we can't help you _extract_ the strings.

Comment: I am looking for java code.. it should work if its works in regex101.com